# Skew detection Opencv Android OCR

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, hough-transform

I'm developing an OCR Android app which uses NDK and C++ in the image processing part. 
In order to understand the skews I'm using Hough Transform and rotating according to the angle returned from it.

It gives robust results but it takes so much time even though I used NDK in order to speed up my app. I wanted to ask if anyone suggests a faster algorithm that I can use?

Comment: How long does it take to calculate the skew? Maybe you can perform the  calculation only once in a while, not at 15 FPS? Also, for preview you can instruct OpenGL to display the deskewed image, without running the rotation on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

i think this two link may help you

[Detect skew angle](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/)

[rotation](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/)

Answer (score 0):

By eroding and boxing the resulting points, you can calculate the angle:

```
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(filename, 0);
    .
    .
    .
    cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 3));
    cv::erode(img, img, element);

    std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();

    for (; it != end; ++it)
       if (*it)
          points.push_back(it.pos());

    cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));

    double angle = box.angle;
    if (angle < -45.)
       angle += 90.;
```

[OpenCV Bouding Box & Skew Angle](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/)